# Is Cat a vahana of any deity in Hinduism?

Tags: gods, vahana

While we encounter many animals as vahanas of the different forms of Hindu deities I am not aware of any references to cats. Can anybody throw light on this? Is there any deity whose vahana is a cat? If not is there a mention anywhere why it is not?

Comment: Goddess Shasti has cat as vahana. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shashthi

Comment: are not tigers cats? Durga's mount is a tiger....

Answer (score 4):

[Shashthi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shashthi) goddess is associated with Cats.

> Shashthi or Shashti (Sanskrit: षष्ठी, Ṣaṣṭhī, literally "sixth") is a
>   Hindu folk goddess, venerated as the benefactor and protector of
>   children (especially, as the giver of male child). She is also the
>   deity of vegetation and reproduction and is believed to bestow
>   children and assist during childbirth. She is often pictured as a
>   motherly figure, riding a cat and nursing one or more infants. She is
>   symbolically represented in a variety of forms, including an
>   earthenware pitcher, a banyan tree or part of it or a red stone
>   beneath such a tree; outdoor spaces termed shashthitala are also
>   consecrated for her worship. The worship of Shashthi is prescribed to
>   occur on the sixth day of each lunar month of the Hindu calendar as
>   well as on the sixth day after a child's birth. Barren women desiring
>   to conceive and mothers seeking to ensure the protection of their
>   children will worship Shashthi and request her blessings and aid. She
>   is especially venerated in eastern India. Chhath is celebrated in
>   Bihar in honour of her and Surya(sun god), twice in a year(In lunar
>   months of Kartik, given more prominence and other one in Chaitra
>   month.)